# Вывод сверху вниз а не снизу вверх SQL запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, select

подскажите как правильно сформировать SELECT чтобы он выводил содержимое сверху вниз с базы а то он выводит снизу вверх.

```
mysql_query('SELECT `id`, `Name`, `Text` FROM `account`');
```

Comment: Смотрите про ORDER BY и ORBER BY DESCENDING

Comment: в реляционных БД нет понятия верха и низа, нет первой и последней записи (если не используется сортировка `ORDER BY ...`) и нет гарантии, что записи при выборке будут читаться в том же порядке в котором записывались в таблицу. Используйте предикат: `ORDER BY`

Comment: @MaxU Пример ордера можно? основанным на моем примере выше чтобы знать

Comment: `'SELECT id, Name, Text FROM account ORDER BY id'`, в убывающем порядке: `'SELECT id, Name, Text FROM account ORDER BY id DESC'`

Comment: @MaxU Благодарю! я не вижу где тут закрыть т.к вы ответили комментарием но все равно балгодарю